# What three odd integers have a sum of 30?

Tags: summation, puzzle, integers

I've been asked the following question:

What three odd integers from the set {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15} that when summed together equals to 30? Note that any integer can be used more than once.

Is there any possibility to solve these kind of questions with some formulae? Note I have gone through the answers for making it with 5 numbers.

Comment: adding odd number of odd numbers can never get you an even number

Comment: There might be some tricky way @ganeshie8

Comment: Odd numbers can be written $2k+1$.  So $(2a+1)+(2b+1)+(2c+1)=2(a+b+c+1)+1=30$.  So when can this occur?

Comment: I dint think I understand adding  three odd numbers gives an odd number

Comment: Well, one might calculate modulo 3, in which case $1+1+1+3+3\equiv 30 (\operatorname{mod} 3)$.

Comment: This was asked on Puzzling.SE yesterday.  There are many non-base 10 solutions.  https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11729/fill-the-holes

Comment: The version on puzzling.SE does not specify "odd integers", it merely specifies the digits of each number. If the base is odd, the last three numbers in the set are even.

Comment: It's the same question, whether you're asking about 5 odd numbers adding up to 30, or three, or seven, or eleven...

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Comment: 9+1+5+5+5+5=30 using 3 integers where one gets used a few times to make up the missing piece.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Note that all the elements of the set are odd.

Hence, even if we repeat, we have, w.l.o.g, the following cases

> (i) Odd $x$ + Odd $x$ + Odd $y$ = Even+Odd=Odd
>
> (ii) Odd $x$ + Odd $y$ + Odd $z$ = Odd
>
> (iii) Odd $x$ + Odd $x$ + Odd $x$ = Even+Odd=Odd

---

.... while $30$ is even.

I actually remember this question which is rumored to be from an IAS exam and no one could solve it except the topper. That's actually a false rumor.

The only way you can get $30$ is by doing it in a *mathematically incorrect* way (by a "trick"), like $7.5+9.5+13=30$

Other than that, this question simply is a bogus question.